# Geometry Nodes: How to add to / shrink / grow index selection or selected indices?

Tags: geometry-nodes

How to add to / shrink / grow index selection or selected indices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way would be to use the *Math: Compare* node or *Compare: Equal* in float mode, and controlling the εpsilon:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can do math operations for selections.

Like in this GIF:

[image]

Larger image of the nodes:

[image]

Note the spreadsheet checkboxes, which indicate the selection. In the beginning every 5th index is selected, then one before those are added and then one after those are added to the selection.

Answer (score 1):

You can manipulate an index selection via Boolean operations.
To add one selection to another simply use the OR boolean operation:

[image]

To grow or shrink (dilate or erode) an index selection is slightly more complicated and you need to check the neighboring indexes via **Sample Index** node. The group node set-ups below check all cases and output the new value for the selection attribute.

[image]

Stacking these groups in a sequence can be used to perform simple morphological operations like adding all indices between selected indices:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Even though this is way more manual labor than using math and modulo and similar

Comment: My assumption is that you start with arbitrary index selection and grow or shrink it in both directions. This cannot be achieved with Modulo operations. If that is not the question then you need to add more details to the initial post with some examples.

Comment: Ah, my initial answer actually achieves grow/shrink with math operations - thank you regardless :)