# Geometry Nodes: How to add to / shrink / grow pre-selected indices?

Tags: geometry-nodes

This handled nicely some mathematical way of selecting indices: [Geometry Nodes: How to add to / shrink / grow index selection or selected indices?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/303151/8282)

But what if I have a pre-selected indices and I want to grow / shrink the selection of those?

How to do this?

[image]

Comment: As hinted by my answer in the linked question, switch the "compare: equal" nodes to "float" modes, connect all their εpsilons to a single "value" node.

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady yes, but the pre-selected indices could be any kind of selection. Like multiple sole index selections coming from the angles of two edges. I rarely define my selections with the equal compare node...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is exactly what I've examined and explained in the previous question.
Just add a chain of two **Grow Selection** groups in the marked by the circle area to achieve the effect you want.

[image]

[image]

I have provided figures how to set up the groups for both Growing and Shrinking a selection of indices.
I would put that group in a Repeat zone in a future version of Blender for ease of use.

Comment: Whoops, sorry. I was actually thinking that for this exact case your solution could be ideal. Perfect! Here's the link to the said answer of yours, just for future reference: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/303192/8282

Comment: Hi Manu, I am glad to help. Cheers!